# Why doesn't this php array_multisort work as intended?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Neither of these work... (nothing is sorted)

I adapted these from an example on the PHP docs site.

```
class ProductHelper {

    function sortProductsByPrice($products, $sort = SORT_ASC) {
        foreach ($products as $key => $row) {
            $name[$key]  = $row['name'];
            $rrp[$key] = $row['rrp'];
        }       
        array_multisort($rrp, $sort, $name, SORT_ASC, $products);
    }

    function sortProductsByName($products, $sort = SORT_ASC) {
        foreach ($products as $key => $row) {
            $name[$key] = $row['name'];
        }
        array_multisort($name, $sort, $products);
    }

}
```

This is how i'm using it:

```
        $products = $cur_prod_cat["products"]; // copy an array of products
        $PRODUCT_HELPER->sortProductsByName($products); //sort it
```

In case you need to see, the products array looks something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 0
        [name] => product name
        [description] => product description
        [price] => product price
        [etc] => other attributes
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [name] => product name
        [description] => product description
        [price] => product price
        [etc] => other attributes
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `return $rrp` in your first one and `return $name` in your second one, after your call to `array_multisort`.

This is because the function is sorting the variables `$rrp` and `$name`, instead of the ones you originally passed to the function.

Edit: If you're simply trying to sort `$products` by it's `name` array value, a better method entirely is the following:

```
function sort_name($a,$b) {
    return strcmp($a['name'],$b['name']);
}

$products = $cur_prod_cat["products"];
usort($products,'sort_name');
```

This uses the function `sort_name` to determine which element in the array to put first.

You can then create more `sort_{value}` functions if you desire, and just change the field value it contains.

Comment: But that would just return one column? Besides, doesn't putting the $products array in the array_multisort function sort the $products array?

Comment: If you look at the php.net function definition: `bool array_multisort ( array &$arr [, mixed $arg = SORT_ASC [, mixed $arg = SORT_REGULAR [, mixed $... ]]] )` - it's the first variable that is referenced and hence sorted, not the other values.

Comment: Ah ok. I also just realised the last param is added to sort by the common key. But if I wanted to sort these columns then return a whole products array, that means I have to copy each column, sort them, and then stick them together?

Comment: The other option would be to pass your function a pointer to the array you want to sort.

Comment: @matthewdavidson I thought you dont need to use pointers in php5?

Comment: I've edited the post to include a method that does what you describe better.

Comment: @Death that looks good but I'm having trouble encapsulating that function in my product helper class. I get errors about the function not being found `'$this->sort_name' not found or invalid function name`

Comment: @Death Nevermind, I managed to do it with a static function like this: `usort($products, 'ProductHelper::sort_name');` thanks for your example!